# How to get text box values dynamically using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I followed the following tutorial for adding two values in Angular;
[Addition of Two Numbers in AngularJS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/879886/Addition-of-Two-Numbers-in-AngularJS)

But now I have to sum dynamic text box values inside ng-repeat.

I have the following Code

**HTML Code**

```
 ......
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Days</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="si in serImp">
                <td>{{si.Name}}</td>
                <td><input type="number" ng-model="si.Days" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        .......
        <button ng-click="sum()">Calculate</button>
        .......
```

**JS code**

```
.........
        $scope.serImp = [];
        $scope.serImp = data;
                // here data is object contain multiple Name+Durations e.g. 
        /*data = 
        [0]
   Name:"first"
   Days: 1
[1]
   Name:"second"
   Days: 2
[2]
   Name:"third"
   Days: 3*/

         $scope.sum = function () {
// sum code goes here
    }
    ........
```

My Question is : **How can I get the sum of the values/numbers from the ng-model="si.Days"**

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce to sum up all the days.
When you modify the values with ng-model you're manipulating the `$scope.serImp` array. You can then use these values to calculate the sum.

```
$scope.sum = function () {
     return $scope.serImp.reduce(function(prv, cur) { 
         return prv.Days + cur.Days; 
     });
}
```

Reduce takes an array and reduces it to one value by applying one function to all of its elements. In our case just simply adding up all the days.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

I will create function that will return all Days total & will directly bind to html

```
{{totalDays()}}
```

**Code**

```
$scope.totalDays = function(){
  var totalDays = 0;
  angular.forEach( $scope.serImp, function(si){
     if(si.Days && !isNaN(si.Days)){
        totalDays += Number(si.Days);
     }
  })
}
```